# Moving Product Tabs

Tags: rwd, tabs, products-view

How do I move the tabs (product collateral) from the bottom of the page to just under the add-to-cart-wrapper? I've tried playing around with view.phtml, but can only get the tabs to appear above the Add To Cart block or at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is you are really trying to achieve. If I understood your problem correctly, then you can do this job by a single cut-paste of code snippet in `view.phtml`.

You need to "cut" the below code from `view.phtml` (Appears very below of the template file)

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

to inside the `add-to-card-wrapper` div.

```
  <div class="add-to-cart-wrapper">
       ....
       <!-- Paste your code here. Just below child elements -->
  </div>
```

This will give you an output like this.

[image]

You can [**find the modified view.phtml file here**](https://gist.github.com/progammer-rkt/a47583804e32b1568844). Have a look on there and understand the changes.